# change theme in wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I created a plugin to change the theme to load if you go to a custom post type but does not work because get_post_type () does not work in my plugin

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Theme post type
 * Plugin URI: ...
 * Description: ...
 * Author: ...
 * Author URI: ...
 * Version: 1.0
 */


        add_filter('template','use_posttype_custom');
        add_filter('stylesheet','use_posttype_custom');

    function use_posttype_custom($themename) {

        if(get_post_type()=='blog'){ return 'new_name'; }else{ return $themename; }
    }

?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ???
`blog` is your custom post type ????

Comment: if it is a post type called blog. I want to change the theme in that post type as it totally changes the html code, css and js